# Best way to do security (menu item/code) for a popup form?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a custom pop-up form that I want to open automatically when you open the CustTable form and I'm trying to figure out what the best way to provide security around this is.

I'd like to have a security privilege/duty/role so that it can be added/removed to user accounts who want the functionality, but there is no "menu button" that is clicked.

What's the most "native" way to open this form from code?

I've found the `Global::hasMenuItemAccess()` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa593278(v=ax.50).aspx

Should I just use this in code or can I change the way I open the form to call the menu item through code?  Or will that just say "user does not have access"?

Comment: It's certainly not a best practice, but if you wanted to use the hasMenuItemAccess method, you could create a dummy menu item and apply certain security to it, then check the method before running your pop-up form

Answer (score 1):

You should still create a menu item for the form that you want to open and use the normal way to secure the menu item with security. Then, you can launch the form using the menu item.

`Args args = new Args();
 ; 
 args.record(VendTable::find("XYZ"));
 new MenuFunction(MenuItemDisplayStr(VendTable),MenuItemType::Display).run(Args);`